# Windows batch job how to echo a command when echo is off

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have searched and searched for this and I can't find the answer.  Maybe it's not possible.  I want to do "echo off" for my whole batch job, BUT i want certain lines to echo.

I know I could put an @ in front of every line and just leave the @ off any lines I DO want to echo.

But is there a way to do:

```
echo off
call setver
if not exist todir md todir
copy myfile.exe todir
```

I want nothing to echo EXCEPT the "copy" statement...

Comment: What's provoking the question? (Why do you need to?)

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
call setver
if not exist todir md todir
ECHO ON
copy myfile.exe todir
@ECHO OFF
```

should do what you want, IIUC.

and for the inevitable follow-up, "how do you echo the word "on"`

```
echo(on
```

where `(` may be any of the usual crew like `.` etc.

Comment: OK thanks for that.  I am already doing that, but I was hoping for a way that was essentially the reverse of the @, that says "echo this line" so I don't have to have "echo on/echo off" pairs all throughout the job, but I guess there's probably no other way...

Answer (score 0):

You could also echo the command itself before executing it.

```
@echo off
call setver
if not exist todir md todir
echo copy myfile.exe todir
copy myfile.exe todir
```

As it can be seen, the command to show visible is just duplicated in file and `echo` is put before. That works also with environment variables referenced on line of the command.

Care must be taken only on a command which contains a redirection as the redirecting angle bracket(s) must be escaped with `^` to output the angle bracket instead of redirecting the message. Example:

```
@echo off
echo set ^>"%TEMP%\AllVariables.txt"
set >"%TEMP%\AllVariables.txt"
del "%TEMP%\AllVariables.txt"
```